# Difference between 'Stored as InputFormat, OutputFormat' and 'Stored as' in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, orc, hive-serde

Issue when executing a `show create table` and then executing the resulting `create table` statement if the table is ORC.

Using `show create table`, you get this:

```
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat’
OUTPUTFORMAT
  ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat’
```

But if you create the table with those clauses, you will then get the casting error when selecting. Error likes:

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.BinaryComparable

To fix this, just change `create table` statement to `STORED AS ORC` 
But, as the answer said in the similar question:
[What is the difference between 'InputFormat, OutputFormat' & 'Stored as' in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416236/what-is-the-difference-between-inputformat-outputformat-stored-as-in-hive) .
I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: As far as I know, `STORED AS ORC` is exactly the same as `STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'`.  It's just shorthand for specifying the fully qualified class for input and output formats.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`STORED AS` implies 3 things:

1. SERDE
2. INPUTFORMAT
3. OUTPUTFORMAT

You have defined only the last 2, leaving the SERDE to be defined by **hive.default.serde**

> **hive.default.serde**
> Default Value: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
> Added in: Hive 0.14 with HIVE-5976
> The default SerDe Hive will use for storage formats that do not specify a SerDe.
> Storage formats that currently do not specify a SerDe include 'TextFile, RcFile'.

#### Demo

**hive.default.serde**

```
set hive.default.serde;
```

---

```
hive.default.serde=org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
```

**STORED AS ORC**

```
create table mytable (i int) 
stored as orc;

show create table mytable;
```

---

Note that the SERDE is `'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'`

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable`(
  `i` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'file:/home/cloudera/local_db/mytable'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='{\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\"}', 
  'numFiles'='0', 
  'numRows'='0', 
  'rawDataSize'='0', 
  'totalSize'='0', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1496982059')
```

---

**STORED AS INPUTFORMAT  ... OUTPUTFORMAT ...**

```
create table mytable2 (i int) 
STORED AS 
INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
;

show create table mytable2
;
```

---

Note that the SERDE is `'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'`

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable2`(
  `i` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'file:/home/cloudera/local_db/mytable2'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='{\"BASIC_STATS\":\"true\"}', 
  'numFiles'='0', 
  'numRows'='0', 
  'rawDataSize'='0', 
  'totalSize'='0', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1496982426')
```

Answer (score 3):

You сan specify `INPUTFORMAT`, `OUTPUTFORMAT`, `SERDE` in `STORED AS` when creating table. Hive allows you to separate your record format from your file format. You can provide custom classes for `INPUTFORMAT`, `OUTPUTFORMAT`, `SERDE`. See details: http://www.dummies.com/programming/big-data/hadoop/defining-table-record-formats-in-hive/

Alternatively you can write simply `STORED AS ORC` or `STORED AS TEXTFILE` for example. 
    STORED AS ORC statement already takes care about `INPUTFORMAT`, `OUTPUTFORMAT` and `SERDE`. This allows you not to write those long fully qualified Java class names for `INPUTFORMAT`, `OUTPUTFORMAT`, `SERDE`. Just `STORED AS ORC` instead.